# Event is always Null, Therefore Can't Be Handled

Tags: c#, class, event-handling

I have 3 classes, one class triggers the event, another calls the event handler sender and finally the last receives the event. However the event handler in the sender class is always `null`, hence the receiver never handles the event. I cannot work out why it is `null` as I assign it as `StartEventHandler` as seen below.

I've tried to enter debug statements to see why the handler was never being run and found that it never gets to class C.

First Class triggers the event:

```
Class A {
    public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        B senders = new B();
        senders.OnPageSwap(new StartEventArgs());
    }
}
```

Second Class is the Sender

```
public delegate void StartEventHandler(object sender, StartEventArgs e);
public class B
{
    public event StartEventHandler PageSwap;
    public virtual void OnPageSwap(StartEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entered PageSwapSender");
        if(PageSwap != null) PageSwap(this, e);
    }
}
```

Third Class is the receiver

```
Class C {
    B sender = new B();

    void Connect()
    {
        sender.PageSwap += new StartEventHandler(this.sender_PageSwap);
        Console.WriteLine("Entered Connect");
    }

    private void sender_PageSwap(object sender, StartEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entered Handler");
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why `PageSwap` in `class B` is always `null` hence never running `PageSwap(this, e)`.

Comment: I don't see any calls to `C.Connect()`, so `sender.PageSwap` never gets subscribed to..?

Comment: Do I need to call C.Connect() to initiate the listener, so its waiting for the event to be triggered?

Comment: Yes, otherwise `C.sender_PageSwap` will not be registered as an event handler for `sender.PageSwap`. There are other problems with the code, though. For each `C`, `C.sender` is initialized to a _new_ `B`, which means that `Connect()` will subscribe to a _different_ `B` than the one created in `A.Button_Click`, so clicking the button will still not result in a call to the event handler... Maybe `Connect()` should instead have a parameter for specifying which `B` to connect the event handler to. Or maybe `C` should have a constructor parameter for specifying which `B` the `C` should listen to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are instantiating two separate instances of the class `B`. In `A` you are trying to raise the event on one instance of `B`. In `C` you are trying to handle the event raised **using a difference instance of `B`**.

It seems that you have tried to do the right thing by creating a `Connect` method in `C`, but this is where you should have **passed the existing instance of `B` through to `C`**.

Had you written your code like this, it would have worked:

```
class A
{   
    public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        B senders = new B();
        C c = new C();
        c.Connect(senders);
        senders.OnPageSwap(new StartEventArgs());
    }
}

public delegate void StartEventHandler(object sender, StartEventArgs e);
public class B
{
    public event StartEventHandler PageSwap;
    public virtual void OnPageSwap(StartEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entered PageSwapSender");
        if (PageSwap != null) PageSwap(this, e);
    }
}

class C
{
    public void Connect(B sender)
    {
        sender.PageSwap += new StartEventHandler(this.sender_PageSwap);
        Console.WriteLine("Entered Connect");
    }

    private void sender_PageSwap(object sender, StartEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entered Handler");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`C.Connect()` is not being called and it needs to, since it's where you are registering the EventHandler that calls `this.sender_PageSwap`. Without that, nothing will happen.

Comment: This would not be enough, class C create a new B object, not using the one created in the A, so it will again not Invoke